# Need to translate Tax word in Swedish as Moms

Tags: tax, i18n

I want to translate the word Tax in order summary
[image]

I have tried adding translation in i18n

[image]

But still no result
here is the code:

```
<tr class="totals-tax">
<th data-bind="text: title" class="mark" scope="row"></th>
```